# convertir cadena con una expresión regular en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

no conozco las expresiones regulares en javascript pero creo que debe ser la manera mas optima de resolver mi problema. Tengo una cadena que procede de mi base de datos que se compone de 4 números separados por comas, estos sirven para agregar un horario en mi sitio. Lo que me gustaría hacer es transformar mi cadena en un formato legible por ejemplo:

```
1200,1215,2200,2230

12:00-12:15 22:00-22:30
```

Un saludo y gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pienso que mejor lo resolverías usando tu propia lógica, por ejemplo usando [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) y [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```js
let valoresFecha = '1200,1215,2200,2230';
valoresFecha = valoresFecha.split(',');

let nuevaFecha = '';
nuevaFecha += valoresFecha[0].slice(0,2) + ':' + valoresFecha[0].slice(2,4) + '-';
nuevaFecha += valoresFecha[1].slice(0,2) + ':' + valoresFecha[1].slice(2,4) + ' ';
nuevaFecha += valoresFecha[2].slice(0,2) + ':' + valoresFecha[2].slice(2,4) + '-';
nuevaFecha += valoresFecha[3].slice(0,2) + ':' + valoresFecha[3].slice(2,4);

console.log(nuevaFecha)
```